# Invoking SQL Loader with a DSN

Tags: windows, oracle, odbc, dsn, sql-loader

I'm trying to load some data to an Oracle database using SQL Loader. Is it possible to invoke it with specifying the server to load the data into using a DSN instead of a TNS?

Right now my command line looks like this: `sqlldr uesr/password@tns_id...`, I'd like to replace `tns_id` with a DSN that points to `tns_id`. Can SQL Loader figure out the TNS from the DSN by itself?

Answer (score 0):

A database can be identified (in Oracle terms) by a hostname, port (generally 1521) and service/sid.

SQL Loader won't be able to work with a DSN itself, but if you can use Windows scripting or similar to worm the host/port/service information out, you'll be most of the way there.

---

With a full client installed and a tnsnames.ora do a

```
tnsping dbname
```

You should get something like

```
Attempting to contact 
(DESCRIPTION = (ENABLE=BROKEN) (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostname)(PORT = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = servname)))
OK (30 msec)
```

You should then be able to do

```
sqlplus user/pass@hostname:1521/servname
```

Comment: how do I format it in the command line? I tried `sqlldr user/password@hostname` but that didn't work.

Comment: user/password@hostname:1521/service_name

Comment: I'm still getting `TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified`

Comment: `tnsping` worked and returned something similiar to what you wrote. I then tried to run `sqlplus` like you said but I got the same error. Not sure why you refered to `sqlplus` as I was originally trying to make `sqlldr` work, but it still didn't.

Comment: sqlplus is just a bit simpler (ie I didn't need any other command line parameters). The error generally indicates it can't find the host. Try PING hostname and see if that returns anything.